# Column value removed on ng-click using tree-grid-directive dynamically

Tags: dynamic, angularjs-ng-repeat, directive, angularjs-ng-click, treegrid

The table created on dynamically using `ng-repeat` with the plugin of Tree-Grid-Directive with the option of Dialog box pop up.

While click on the column value it pop up correctly using `ng-click`. But after closing dialog box, the td value is missing. I have checked with CSS and coding also. I couldn't find it.

My code is :

```
<td ng-repeat="col in colDefinitions" ng-controller="treeGridController" 
  ng-click="(col.field!='col1' && row.branch[col.field]>50)?  openTemplate(col.field,row.branch):' ' " ng-    style=\"set_color(row.branch[col.field],col.field)\">{{row.branch[col.field]}}</td>
```

In Inspect Element :

```
<td ng-repeat="col in colDefinitions" ng-controller="treeGridController" ng-click="(col.field!='col1'&amp;&amp;row.branch[col.field]>50)?openTemplate(col.field,row.branch):''" ng-style="set_color(row.branch[col.field],col.field)" class="ng-scope ng-binding"></td>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly so it's readable. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Hi Piotr, Have formatted. Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: The Plugin Link is : http://khan4019.github.io/tree-grid-directive/test/treeGrid.html

Comment: Hi MegaTron, Thanks for edited my Query.

Answer (score 0):

We have simply solved with funny work as by changing the function name (openTemplate) to test1 after 3 days

Comment: Did you have any JavaScript errors in your browser console? I wonder if `name()` is a reserved function name in Angular?

Comment: Hi, It is not with name(). We had changed the function name as 'openTemplate()' to 'test()'. Then It is working.

Comment: OK. For the sake of useful detail for future readers, why do you think that fixed it?